# Mount NFS share from WSL in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, nfs, wsl2

I installed a Windows 10 with a WSL Ubuntu. For some reasons, I need to have some files in a Linux only filesystem that I created in /some/path.

Since I need to access that folder from Windows, I added a NFS export in Linux (WSL):

```bash
/home/user/some/path *(rw,async,no_subtree_check)
```

Then, in Windows powershell, I executed:

```bash
New-PSdrive -PSProvider FileSystem -Name M -Root \\192.168.111.111\home\user\some\path -Persist -v
```

And I get this verbose message:

```bash
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "New drive" on target "Name: M Provider: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem Root: \\192.168.111.111\home\user\some\path".
```

And then nothing happens. No connection, no nothing.

Any ideas why the NFS share is not mounted? Or what can I do to troubleshoot?

Comment: @harrymc's answer addresses the core issue, but for NFS, it needs to be enabled within `optionalfeatures` → _Services for NFS_

Answer (score 1):

You don't need NFS shares to access WSL Ubuntu from Windows,
by using the built-in share.

You can address the files directly with :

```
\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\some\path
```